# Make TextBlock text appear character by character

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

I'm trying to style a `TextBlock` to make it look like everytime I update its content, the content updates like we were typing it in, character by character. Can someone start me off in the right direction? I have no clue what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a Behavior (there are lots of examples out there on creating these). In your case, you could just create a Behavior.

Since the TextBlock doesn't expose a TextChanged event, you'd probably have to hook into the binding for the Text property and then run your code. You could clear the text to an empty string and then add the characters one by one with a delay (note: you'd need to quit listening for changes to Text while you're updating it).